# How to remove one white space if two white space found between string in php?

Tags: php

I want to remove one white space if found two white space between phrase in php, I can detect if there is two white space or not, but I can not remove white space, here is how I tried,

```html
my_doublespace = "Marketing  and Sales Staff";
if(strpos($my_doublespace, '  ') > 0){
    
dd('including double space');

}
else{
    dd('no double');
}
```

I want the result like this "Marketing and Sales Staff", only one white space between "Marketing" and "and". Is there anyway to remove it?

Comment: What if you have 3 whitespaces, should they be changed to 1?

Comment: yes i would change to 1 bro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this

```
$str = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $str);
```

This will change 2 or more spaces to a single space.

Because, do you want 3 spaces becoming 2, which is the result of some of the other answers.

I would toss a `trim()` in to the mix for good measure.

You can "roll" your own trim like this:

```
$str = preg_replace(['/\s{2,}/','/^\s+|\s+$/'],[' ',''], $str);
```

You can try this live [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0851dc1fb21089cb49d01898901505c973afb3ba)

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)?

I.e.

```
 $my_doublespace = preg_replace('/  /', ' ', $my_doublespace);
```

Answer (score 2):

`str_replace` function also works fine.

```
$my_doublespace = str_replace('  ', ' ', $my_doublespace);
```